# Display Content Type Field in region--footer.tpl.php

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

First of all I am overriding the default footer template with my own using **region--footer.tpl.php**. In the footer I need to display the fields I have in a content type named 'footer'. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: fast and dirty?

Comment: yeah.....i need the fields seperately so i can hold each field in seperate variables using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said, fast and dirty:

```
$nid = XXX;
$node = node_load($nid);
print check_plain($node->field_name['und'][0]['value']);
```

Put this into your Template. I assume your field is not translated.

Comment: Cool thanks @Benone_ its working...I can have leave from work for christmas now :P lol .......I will ask Santa to give u a big gift :P